# How to deal with null row appended at the end of windows generated csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a function to deal with the null values in the csv before passing it to a forecasting model

```
if do_nulls_exist == True:
    print('found a null value')
    null_rows = pd.isnull(data)
    print('######### ORIGINAL ROWS THAT NEED UPDATING ##############')
    print(null_rows)
    # Need to add 2 to each value in null_rows because there

    print('######### ROWS + 2 = ACTUAL ROW NUMBERS IN CSV ##############')
    update_these_rows = []
    for x in null_rows:
        update_these_rows.append(int(x)+2)

    print(update_these_rows)

    emit('error', {'data': update_these_rows})
```

[image: Error in the backend]

As you can see the there is a null row appended at the end (Row no 36)

Pls guide me as to how I can remove this null row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before passing CSV to forecast model you can apply **dropna()** function on Dataframe. It will delete all null row's

```
    df = df.dropna()
```

Refe Link :[dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: Tried it. Not working. The problem is as soon as you use windows csv, it again appends null row at the end